# Can't connect to Anyconnect via cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, vpn, cisco

I am trying to automate my system to connect to a client's VPN for a couple hours every night.  The client requires us to us Cisco's Anyconnect VPN Client, but we're having some difficulties.  I've made an executable bash script to automatically launch the VPN client, enter user/pass, etc., and what I'd like to do is run the script automatically each night using cron.  If I just run the script manually, everything works just fine, and the VPN connects right up.  But running the script using cron, the VPN won't connect.  Below is the relevant portion of the syslog file.

```
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getLocalizationPath File: ../../vpn/Common/i18n/MsgCatalog.cpp Line: 621 Invoked Function: CInstanceSmartPtr<StoragePath> Return Code: -24641526 (0xFE88000A) Description: CSTORAGEPATH_ERROR_NO_INSTANCE
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Initializing vpnapi version 4.3.05017 ().
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: loadProfiles File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 100 No profile is available.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getCurrentState File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfcBase.cpp Line: 2120 API service not ready
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Current Preference Settings: ServiceDisable: false CertificateStoreOverride: false CertificateStore: All ShowPreConnectMessage: false AutoConnectOnStart: false MinimizeOnConnect: true LocalLanAccess: false AutoReconnect: true AutoUpdate: true ProxySettings: Native AllowLocalProxyConnections: true PPPExclusion: Disable PPPExclusionServerIP:  EnableScripting: false TerminateScriptOnNextEvent: false EnableAutomaticServerSelection: false AuthenticationTimeout: 12 IPProtocolSupport: IPv4,IPv6 AllowManualHostInput: true BlockUntrustedServers: true PublicProxyServerAddress:
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: findProfile File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 671 Unable to locate NSS profile directory from /root/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: InitNSS File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 397 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::getProfilePath Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: CNSSCertStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertStore.cpp Line: 76 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::InitNSS Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: addNSSStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 1766 Invoked Function: CNSSCertStore::CNSSCertStore Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: OpenStores File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 423 Invoked Function: CCollectiveCertStore::addNSSStore Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: OnNegotiateMessageTypesComplete File: ../../vpn/Api/ApiIpc.cpp Line: 755 Master Agent Connection started.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: VPN state: Disconnected Network state: Network Accessible Network control state: Network Access: Available Network type: Undefined
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: setConnectRequestComplete File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 9327 Connect request complete. Proceeding to cleanup.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: activateConnectEvent File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 1431 NULL object. Cannot establish a connection at this time.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Message type information sent to the user: Ready to connect.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: attach File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfcBase.cpp Line: 667 Client successfully attached.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: WMHintCB File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfc.cpp Line: 152 User did not implement WMHintCB.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: WMHintCB File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfc.cpp Line: 152 User did not implement WMHintCB.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: An SSL VPN connection to vpn.gillettechildrens.com/UHL has been requested by the user.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getProfileNameFromHost File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 808 No profile available for host vpn.gillettechildrens.com.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getHostInitSettings File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 888 Profile () not found. Using default settings.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: deliverWebLaunchHostCB File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfc.cpp Line: 158 User did not implement deliverWebLaunchHostCB.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: loadProfiles File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 100 No profile is available.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getProfileNameFromHost File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 808 No profile available for host vpn.gillettechildrens.com.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Using default preferences. Some settings (e.g. certificate matching) may not function as expected if a local profile is expected to be used. Verify that the selected host is in the server list section of the profile and that the profile is configured on the secure gateway.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getProfileNameFromHost File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 808 No profile available for host vpn.gillettechildrens.com.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getHostInitSettings File: ../../vpn/Api/ProfileMgr.cpp Line: 888 Profile () not found. Using default settings.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getCertList File: ../../vpn/Api/ApiCert.cpp Line: 339 Number of certificates found: 0
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Message type information sent to the user: Contacting vpn.gillettechildrens.com/UHL.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Initiating VPN connection to the secure gateway https://vpn.gillettechildrens.com/UHL
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Using default preferences. Some settings (e.g. certificate matching) may not function as expected if a local profile is expected to be used. Verify that the selected host is in the server list section of the profile and that the profile is configured on the secure gateway.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: processConnectNotification File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 12205 Received connect notification (host vpn.gillettechildrens.com/UHL, profile N/A)
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: resolveHostNameAlt File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HostLocator.cpp Line: 623 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Description: DNSREQUEST_ERROR_NO_DNS_RESOLVERS
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: resolveHostName File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HostLocator.cpp Line: 718 Invoked Function: CHostLocator::resolveHostNameAlt Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Description: DNSREQUEST_ERROR_NO_DNS_RESOLVERS
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: getHostIPAddrByName File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketSupport.cpp Line: 323 Invoked Function: ::getaddrinfo Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: unknown
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: resolveHostName File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HostLocator.cpp Line: 730 Invoked Function: CSocketSupport::getHostIPAddrByName Return Code: -31195124 (0xFE24000C) Description: SOCKETSUPPORT_ERROR_GETADDRINFO
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: ResolveHostname File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HostLocator.cpp Line: 839 Invoked Function: CHostLocator::resolveHostName Return Code: -31195124 (0xFE24000C) Description: SOCKETSUPPORT_ERROR_GETADDRINFO failed to resolve host name vpn.gillettechildrens.com to IPv6 address
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: logResolutionResult File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/HostLocator.cpp Line: 913 Host vpn.gillettechildrens.com has been resolved to IP address 205.215.216.4
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Writing to hosts file:  205.215.216.4#011vpn.gillettechildrens.com ###Cisco AnyConnect VPN client modified this file. Please do not modify contents until this comment is removed.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: respondToConnectNotification File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 5338 The requested VPN connection to vpn.gillettechildrens.com/UHL will target the following IP protocols and addresses: primary - IPv4 (address 205.215.216.4), secondary - N/A.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: getUserName File: ../../vpn/Api/CTransportCurlStatic.cpp Line: 2045 PasswordEntry username is root
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: findProfile File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 671 Unable to locate NSS profile directory from /root/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: InitNSS File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 397 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::getProfilePath Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: CNSSCertStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertStore.cpp Line: 76 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::InitNSS Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: addNSSStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 1766 Invoked Function: CNSSCertStore::CNSSCertStore Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: OpenStores File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 423 Invoked Function: CCollectiveCertStore::addNSSStore Return Code: -31457265 (0xFE20000F) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERTSTORE_NOT_FOUND
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Server certificate validation failed with the following errors:  #011Certificate is from an untrusted source.
Mar  5 08:28:01 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Untrusted VPN server(vpn.gillettechildrens.com) encountered. AnyConnect is currently configured to block untrusted servers.
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: PeerCertVerifyCB File: ../../vpn/Api/CTransportCurlStatic.cpp Line: 957 Invoked Function: ITransportCB::OnPeerCertVerificationError Return Code: -31391702 (0xFE21002A) Description: CERTIFICATE_ERROR_USER_DECLINED_UNTRUSTED_CERT_ACCEPTANCE:User has declined to accept an untrusted server certificate
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: TranslateCertificateErrors File: ../../vpn/Api/CTransport.cpp Line: 749 Invoked Function: Certificate Error Return Code: -31391702 (0xFE21002A) Description: CERTIFICATE_ERROR_USER_DECLINED_UNTRUSTED_CERT_ACCEPTANCE:User has declined to accept an untrusted server certificate Translated to CTRANSPORT_ERROR_PEER_CERT_REJECTED
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: sendRequest File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectIfc.cpp Line: 3219 Invoked Function: CTransport::SendRequest Return Code: -30015455 (0xFE360021) Description: CTRANSPORT_ERROR_PEER_CERT_REJECTED
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: connect File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectIfc.cpp Line: 481 Invoked Function: ConnectIfc::sendRequest Return Code: -30015455 (0xFE360021) Description: CTRANSPORT_ERROR_PEER_CERT_REJECTED
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: TranslateStatusCode File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectIfc.cpp Line: 3036 Invoked Function: TranslateStatusCode Return Code: -30015455 (0xFE360021) Description: CTRANSPORT_ERROR_PEER_CERT_REJECTED Connection attempt failed.  Please try again.
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: doConnectIfcConnect File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 2062 Invoked Function: ConnectIfc::connect Return Code: -30015455 (0xFE360021) Description: CTRANSPORT_ERROR_PEER_CERT_REJECTED
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Message type warning sent to the user: Connection attempt has failed.
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: processIfcData File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 2742 Content type (unknown) received. Response type (undefined) from vpn.gillettechildrens.com:
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: connect File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 2149 ConnectMgr::processIfcData failed
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: initiateConnect File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 1252 Connection failed.
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: VPN state: Disconnected Network state: Network Accessible Network control state: Network Access: Available Network type: Undefined
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: run File: ../../vpn/Api/ConnectMgr.cpp Line: 719 Invoked Function: ConnectMgr::initiateConnect Return Code: -29622263 (0xFE3C0009) Description: CONNECTMGR_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpncli[4379]: Function: detach File: ../../vpn/Api/ClientIfcBase.cpp Line: 480 Shutting down vpnapi
Mar  5 08:28:02 SKYSPARK acvpnagent[1323]: Function: OnIpcMessageReceived File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/IPCDepot.cpp Line: 1070 Invoked Function: CIpcTransport::OnSocketReadComplete Return Code: -33292279 (0xFE040009) Description: IPCTRANSPORT_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.  It seems like a possible solution might be to allow connection to untrusted servers, but in the GUI, the "Block Connection to Untrusted Servers" is NOT checked, and I can't find that option in the AnyConnectProfile.xml.

I've been fighting with this for a while and am pretty much stumped.  By no means am I a networking expert, or a Linux OS expert.  I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Upon review the syslog file when I connect my manually executing the script, it seems the issue is that the certificate successful validates when run manually, but fails to validate when run via cron.

Also, sudo is used within the script, but I am running it as a user WITHOUT root privileges - and I am using the root-level crontab (I think).  I access it using "sudo crontab -e".

Answer (score 0):

anyconnect does not support linux 16 https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCuy92565/?reffering_site=dumpcr